# Как из массива вернуть определенные строки

Tags: javascript, массивы

Допустим есть массив, нужно вернуть из него только те слова, которые начинаются с #, но без этого символа.
Пока я только разделил массив на строки, а как достать из него то, что мне нужно затрудняюсь.

```js
 {
    var weather = '#Сегодня будет теплая #погода';

    var arr = weather.split(' '); //[ '#Сегодня', 'будет', 'теплая', '#погода' ]


    console.info( arr ); 
    //[ 'Сегодня', 'погода' ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var rez = arr.filter(x=>x[0]=='#').map(y=>y.substring(1,y.length));
```

`filter` фильтрует все значения на предмет выполнения, аргумент это функция возвращающая `true - false` (предикат).

`map` создаёт новые элементы на основе старых, то что возвращает лямбда это содержание нового массива

`x[0]` это первый символ строки

Вот тут код - https://jsfiddle.net/Lcx75du5/

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: так вывести надо `rez`, я добавил код для теста https://jsfiddle.net/Lcx75du5/

Comment: да, они вывелись, но остались так же с символом #, а нужно без него

Comment: результат записывается в моём коде в `rez`

Comment: а, понял, сейчас дополню, забыл что вы попросили убрать решётку

Comment: поправил.......

Comment: спасибо! все работает

Comment: можете, тогда отметить как ответ

Comment: @Alex Странное решение использовать три цикла, вместо одного маленького регулярного выражения из другого ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Первый вариант - выбрать регуляркой слова с решёткой перед ними (включая решётку) и потом у выбранных слов отпилить решётку:

```js
let str = "#Сегодня будет теплая #погода";
let pattern = /(#[а-яё]+)/gi;
let result = str.match(pattern).map(el => el.substr(1));
console.log(result);
```

---

Второй вариант без `map` - продвинутой регуляркой:

```js
let str = "#Сегодня будет теплая #погода #течЁт речка";
let pattern = /(?<=#)([а-яё]+)/gi;
let result = str.match(pattern);
console.log(result);
```

`(?<=шаблон)` - Позитивный просмотр назад. Более подробно: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Просмотр_вперёд_и_назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4)